# Rename a jQuery already bound event

Tags: jquery, events, bind

My jQuery plugin trigger events for predeterminated events, like `plugin:json` and `plugin:params`. Right now, I'm trying to stop the custom event from propagate up to the other parents, so I'm half way through, by namespacing the events. However, when a person binds the event without the namespace, the event won't trigger.

So instead of `$(el).on('plugin:json', function(){})`, the person has to input `$(el).on('plugin:json.namespace', function(){});`, but it's a new way to bind events, my last version of the plugin didn't have this requirement for older versions of the plugin, and might break existing code if people upgrade or the code refactoring might be too much.

So, can I check if elements have bound events, and rename them with the proper namespace? I know the undocumented `$._data` from jQuery can list events, I want the plugin to be performant while still being able to rename it properly. Like trigger ALL events in all DOM elements, and depending if they "answer" to my trigger, rename them.